# multi dimensional list c++ STL list

Tags: c++, stl

whats wrong with this simple program. I want to create multi list and insert using c++  STL.  its giving segmentation fault.

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
int main(){
        list<int> *l;
        l[0].push_back(1);
        l[10].push_back(12);
        cout<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't your compile warn you about how you're using the pointer `l` uninitialized? You don't actually have a `list<int>` in your program. You only have a pointer to one. Also please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10411602).

Comment: Hi, its compiled successfully

Comment: Pointers are not arrays. (And arrays are not pointers.)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve??

Comment: You don't have a mutli-dimensional list. You only have a pointer, which COULD point to a one-dimensional list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you using a pointer to a list? You didn't allocate memory for the list. You could use a container to store multiple lists, e.g. std:array for static number of elements or std::vector for dynamic number of elements:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
using std::array;
using std::vector;
using std::list;
using std::cout;

int main(){
        std::array<list<int>, 11> l;
        l[0].push_back(1);
        l[10].push_back(12);


        std::vector<list<int>> l2(11);
        l2[0].push_back(1);
        l2[10].push_back(12);
        cout << '\n';
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`list<int> *l;` makes `l` a pointer to a `list<int>` but it doesn't actually create a `list<int>` - and definitely not an array of `list<int>` which you are trying to access.

Possible solutions.

Plain C fixed size arrays of `list<int>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main() {
    std::list<int> l[11];            // place for 11 list<int>`'s
    l[0].push_back(1);
    l[10].push_back(12);
}
```

Using the C++ fixed sized std::array:

```
#include <array>
#include <list>

int main() {
    std::array<std::list<int>, 11> l; // place for 11 list<int>'s
    l[0].push_back(1);
    l[10].push_back(12);
}
```

Using a C++ `std::vector` that allows for dynamicially adding more `list<int>`'s:

```
#include <list>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::list<int>> l(11); // starts with place for 11 list<int>'s
    l[0].push_back(1);
    l[10].push_back(12);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`list<int> *l;` is a pointer to list, it is not initialized, so adding elements to it has undefined behaviour. Either you initialize it to a variable like:

```
list<int> l;
l.push_back(1);
l.push_back(12);
```

In this case you can only access the elements that already have data, l[0] or l[1].

Or you need to allocate space to the number of elements you need in your list.

For instance:

```
list<int> l[20];
l[0].push_back(1);
l[10].push_back(12);
```

Comment: not wrong but also not quite complete. Initializing `l` alone is not the solution, eg `list<int> *l = nullptr;` is a initialized pointer

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Yes, well put, edited it, better?

Answer (score 0):

In `list<int> *l;` is creating a pointer to a `list`. Before accessing `l` you need to assign valid address to it.

Something like this,

```
list<int> l;
list<int> *l2 = &l;
```